# Printing symbols from an array of chars

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have to solve a small problem:
for a given array of chars,

```
char[] lista = {'a', '2', '?', 'd', '!', 'S', '3', 'D', 'k'};
```

I must:

1. Print only the vowels;
2. Print only the consonants;
3. Print the numbers and;
4. Print the others symbols.

I’m having problems in 4.

My code so far:

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    char [] lista = {'a', '2', '?', 'd', '!', 'S', '3', 'D', 'k'};
    char [] vogal = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};
    char [] numbers = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
    char [] leters = {'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z','B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    char [] symbols = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o','u','A','E','I','O','U','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0','b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z','B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    for (char j=0; j<lista.length ; j++)
    for (char i=0; i<vogal.length ; i++ ){
    if ( vogal [i] == lista [j] )
    System.out.println( "the vowels are: " + vogal [i] );
    }

    for (char j=0; j<lista.length ; j++)
    for (char x=0; x<numbers.length ; x++ ) {    
    if ( numbers [x] == lista [j] )
        System.out.println( "the numbers are: " + numbers [x] );       
    }

    for (char j=0; j<lista.length ; j++)
    for (char y=0; y<leters.length ; y++ ) {    
    if ( leters [y] == lista [j] )
        System.out.println( "the leters are: " + leters [y] );       
    }
        //my main problem is here 
    for (char j=0; j<lista.length ; j++)
    for (char z=0; z<symbols.length ; z++ ){    
    if (symbols [z] != lista [j])
         System.out.println( "the symbols are: " + lista [j]); 
}
 }
    }
```

Any suggestion about how to print the symbols?
Thanks.

Comment: What actually happens when you try to print symbols?

Comment: Why does your symbols array contain letters and not symbols?

Comment: why do you use a `char` instead of an `int` as an array index ?  `char [] lista =` should probably read `char [] lista = ...`. And your indentation of the inner for loops is misleading...

Comment: @CarlNorum I dont know all the symbols.I thought I could match my “symbols” array with the “list”, and then check what was missing in the “symbols” array.  I should call the array “noSymbols”.

Comment: @Lion ... it prints the "list" array a few times each char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the inverse of

- print if at least one in the reference set (e.g. symbols) matches

is NOT

- print if at least one in the reference set does NOT match

but

- print if NONE in the reference set matches.

In other words, you should break the inner loop over z as soon as `lista[j]` is equal to `symbols[z]` and only print that it is a symbol once you have found no match in `symbols`.

(I'm not providing explicit code here as this is homework)

Answer (score 2):

If by "symbols" you mean "not numbers or letters": You can check if a character is not a number nor a letter - and print it if it is none of them.

Have a `boolean flag` [initialized to `true`] while iterating over the `letters` and `numbers`, and set it to `false` if you find a match to one of them.

If at the end of the iteration it is still `true` - it is a symbol.

I know it is homework so you might not be allowed to - but if you can use a [`HashSet<Character>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) - it will probably simplify life for you.

Comment: Would also suggest using `java.lang.Character`. Has useful convenience methods such as `isLetter` and `isDigit`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the for loops. You can instead have a string with required characters and then you can check if given character is contained in the string. Also you can make use of Character class to check whether a char represents letter/digit etc.

Eg:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      char[] list = {'a', '2', '?', 'd', '!', 'S', '3', 'D', 'k'}; 

      for (char c: list) {
          if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
              System.out.println(c + " is a Letter");

              if ("aeiouAEIOU".contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
                  System.out.println(c  + " is a vowel ");                    
              }
              else {
                  System.out.println(c + " is a consonant");
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

For your specific question about :

```
for (char j=0; j<lista.length ; j++)
    for (char z=0; z<symbols.length ; z++ ){    
    if (symbols [z] != lista [j])
         System.out.println( "the symbols are: " + lista [j]);
```

Here you should have a boolean flag to check if the value is not contained in no_symbols array.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to deal with Strings a collection of characters.

```
String list = "a2?d!S3Dk";
String vowel = "aeiouAEIOU";

for(char ch : list.toCharArray()) {
   if (Character.isDigit(ch))
      System.out.print(ch + " is a digit");
   else if (Character.isLetter(ch))
      System.out.print(ch + " is a letter");
   else
      System.out.print(ch + " is a symbol");

   if (vowel.indexOf(ch) >= 0)
      System.out.print(" and a vowel.");
  System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
a is a letter and a vowel.
2 is a digit
? is a symbol
d is a letter
! is a symbol
S is a letter
3 is a digit
D is a letter
k is a letter
```